# Apache Mina SSL proxy (sort of)

Tags: java, http, proxy, server, apache-mina

I need to implement sort of http proxy with SSL support. SSL works fine and I need to parse the incomming message to be either HTTP request or *other*.

How I was thinking it could work:

```
1. in messageReceived I should check I will check if first "maximum-length
  of HTTP request method name length" amout of bytes converted to string
  (new String(byte[]) starts with any of HTTP method name (e.g. GET,POST..)

2a) If so, let's tread this session as HTTP request, grap whole request and
  send it to another HTTP server, wait for response, return the response and
  close the connection.

2b) Otherwise, this is binary tcp connection with data, I want to keep this
  connection alive and play with incoming data/send data to it.
```

The problem is, that in messageReceived() callback, I receive sometimes complete, sometimes incomplete data of HTTP request and it gets called multiple times. E.g. when I run HTTP request against the port, it gets called e.g. once with only first http line + headers, THEN it get's called with POST data.

I have set up the TCP listening using mina like this:

```
IoAcceptor acceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor();
int port = 5555; //whatever

DefaultIoFilterChainBuilder chain = acceptor.getFilterChain();
// ssl support
SslFilter sslFilter = new SslFilter(MySslContextFactory.getInstance(true));
chain.addFirst("sslFilter", sslFilter);             

// handling
acceptor.setHandler( new TCPHandler() );

// listening at 0.0.0.0:5555
acceptor.bind( new InetSocketAddress(port) );
```

TCPHandler.java messageReceived snippet looks like this:

```
@Override
public void messageReceived( IoSession session, Object message ) throws Exception
    IoBuffer msgBuffer = (IoBuffer)message;
    byte[] msgBytes = msgBuffer.array();
    msgBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(msgBytes, 0, msgBuffer.limit());
}
```

I am not sure how/when to check that I have read ALL DATA of HTTP request. It often comes in bunches of data (when checking for msgBytes variable)